# while compiling it on remix i am getting this type error :Operator - not compatible with types tuple() and int_const 1

Tags: solidity, remix

```
  function setvalue(string memory _name,string memory _description,string memory _uses,string memory _ingredients,string memory _sideeffects,string memory _warnings)public{
      Tablet storage data =tablets[_name];
      
      data.name.push(_name);
      data.description.push(_description);
      data.uses.push(_uses);
      data.ingredients.push(_ingredients);
      data.sideeffects.push(_sideeffects);
      data.warnings.push(_warnings);

      require(!alreadyexist[_name]);
      nextdrug.push(_name)-1;
      alreadyexist[_name] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to change your setter() methods about Tablet struct in this way:

```
function setvalue(string memory _name,string memory _description,string memory _uses,string memory _ingredients,string memory _sideeffects,string memory _warnings)public{
      Tablet storage data = tablets[_name];

      // Push is only avaiable when you add an entire tuple.
      // In this case a single tuple must contain (name, description, uses, ingredients, sideeffects, warnings)
      // To resolve your problem you have to change 'push' keyword with '=' to assign input parameter value to struct attribute

      data.name = _name;
      data.description = _description;
      data.uses = _uses;
      data.ingredients = _ingredients;
      data.sideeffects = _sideeffects;
      data.warnings = _warnings;

      require(!alreadyexist[_name]);
      nextdrug.push(_name);
      alreadyexist[_name] = true;
    }
```